# User has to be logged in to see some text

Tags: reactjs, firebase, authentication, npm, firebase-authentication

*Using Firebase v9, NPM, ReactJS*

Hi everybody,

how can I display some text in order, that user is signed in?
e.g:

```
if(loggedIn){
<p>you are logged in</p>
} else if(notLoggedIn){
<p>you arent logged in</p>
}
```

Already have done Firebase auth with email and password.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Set an authentication state observer and get user data

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#set_an_authentication_state_observer_and_get_user_data

follow this link it will get you where do you need

its somethings like that

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, see docs for a list of available properties
    // https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User
    // show message user is logged in
    const uid = user.uid;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out
    // show message user is not logged in
  }
});
```

Comment: I mean, how can I do that with my existing code in question. Your answer forces me to completely re-write my code.